# How exactly does recursion interact with variable scopes?

Tags: python, recursion, scope, memoization

While solving a leetcode problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-difference-between-node-and-ancestor), I stumbled upon a strange (and, to me, unexpected) behavior.

A working solution is as follows:

```
class Solution:
  def maxAncestorDiff(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
    ancestors = []
    max_diff = [0] 

    def dfs(node):
        for v in ancestors:
            if abs(v-node.val) > max_diff[0]:
                max_diff[0] = abs(v-node.val)

        ancestors.append(node.val)

        if node.left:
            dfs(node.left)
        if node.right:
            dfs(node.right)
        
        ancestors.pop()

    dfs(root)
    return max_diff[0]
```

However, simply modifying the code as follows (making max_diff an int instead of a list):

```
class Solution:
  def maxAncestorDiff(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
    ancestors = []
    max_diff = 0 # Instead of [0]

    def dfs(node):
        for v in ancestors:
            if abs(v-node.val) > max_diff:
                max_diff = abs(v-node.val)

        ancestors.append(node.val)

        if node.left:
            dfs(node.left)
        if node.right:
            dfs(node.right)
        
        ancestors.pop()

    dfs(root)
    return max_diff
```

makes the code execution fail with error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'max_diff' referenced before assignment
> if abs(v-node.val) > max_diff:

My understanding is that max_diff should resolve correctly by looking up 'max_diff' in the outer variable scope (the one of maxAncestorDiff), the same way it does for 'ancestors' and when "max_diff" is a list.

Of course a simple solution to make 'max_diff' an int would be to pass it as an argument to dfs, but I would like to understand why my naive solution does not work. I imagine it's related to the fact that lists are mutable while int are not, but why exactly that makes a difference for scope resolution remains a mystery.

Comment: When the function object is *made* (before it is executed) the assignment,  `max_diff = abs(v-node.val)`, makes it local to `dfs`. The other version just mutates a variable in the outer scope.

Comment: I see, and that also explains why ancestors was not an issue (while it becomes one if instead of append I do an assignment "ancestors += [node.val]"). Thank you so much !